# Cannot get the same md5 hash of photo client-side to successfully pass Firebase Storage security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security, cryptojs

I'd like to upload files with uniform names by generating a md5 hash client-side. However, I didn't manage to successfully pass the Firebase Storage security rules at this point:

```
match /{userUid}/{photoHash} {
  allow create: if request.resource.md5Hash == photoHash;
}
```

Client-side code snippet uploading the photo:

```
const compressedPhoto = await this.compressPhoto(photo)
const base64 = await this.toBase64(compressedPhoto)

const photoHash = CryptoJS.MD5(compressedPhoto).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)

const uploadTask = this.storageRef.child(photoHash).put(compressedPhoto)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that should be allowed by this rule.  Without seeing code, there's no telling what is going wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my question, I'm using 'crypto-js' library to compute md5 hash.